# Combining multiple where conditions in mysql SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

So here's my issue:

I have a database table where I have latitudes and longitudes and a timestamp.  I need to be able to search through this table using PHP.  What would the query be to find rows with lats and lons in a certain range, and, on top of this, in a certain time frame.

I have found two separate queries that would work while browsing through the internet, but I can't find a clear way to combine multiple conditions.

The two queries are:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
  cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * 
  sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

enter code here

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_field` BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

I need to find top twenty results where timestamp and lat and long are in range.
Thanks!

EDIT: All fields are in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all data is in the same table, you can do:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM markers
WHERE date_field BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Note it is not allowed to reference a column alias in a WHERE clause. The reason is by the time the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined (think about `sum(num) as total`)

Comment: @MostyMostacho, I just copied and pasted the OP's `SELECT` statement as that's how he has it. I'm merely showing how to combine the two different queries. Feel free to edit if you think it really needs it. `'date1'` and `'date2'` is not allowed either, but that's also how the OP has it :)

Comment: Done. Note the OP doesn't have the `distance` field in the `where` clause for a reason (the reason is my first comment).

Comment: so what is the consensus? Will the above query work?

Comment: @matt, yes, it should do. Obviously you have to put the correct dates and date formats in to the WHERE clause and I cannot vouch for the LAT/LON calculations in the SELECT clause, as that is just confusing without properly testing :)

Comment: No errors are popping up, but no results are coming back either and their should be.  Took the coordinates of one row in table and made sure I picked a spot to compare it to that was within the radius and nothing came back.

Comment: @matt. Go back to the coordinates query you found online and test that on its own, without my date additions. If that doesn't work, then perhaps the algorithm is incorrect or your database setup is incorrect. Try it and let me know.

Comment: NEVERMIND I GOT IT! I got the center coords mixed up with the values that were supposed to come from the table fields.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @matt, I'm very pleased. Good luck with the rest of your project. Make sure you accept this answer so it closes it.